# В всплывающее окно автокомплита грузится весь сайт

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis-10

Сайт написан на asp.net mvc 5 плюс jquery. Есть input с поиском. Сделал к нему всплывающее окно с автокомплитом. На локальном компе(windows10 64),как на IIS так и на IIS express все гут. [image: на iis express]

[image: на iis]

Хостинг у меня на VDS winserver 2016. На хостинге наблюдаю такую беду - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кстати, в разделе контакты карты не отображаются, но на локальной копии сайта тоже яндекс карты открываются(api yandex maps). Куда копать?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался-   во всем виноват модуль реврайтер(https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) и редиректы(правила в webconfig https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vyunev/2011/09/28/iis-url-rewrite-module-2-10/) -  авокомплит не успевает отработать, этот модуль его перехватывал